# Rearranging UIAlertView's button layout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview

just a quick question. 
Is it possible to change layout of UIAlertView's buttons? Two of them look nice
[image: Two buttons]

However three buttons and more waste so much space with, is there any way to re arrange them? So they are in horizontal order like with two buttons?

Default layout is :

[image: Three buttons]

Only thing that come to my mind is to create view, add buttons on that view and add it as a subview to UIAlertView...

Comment: Why not just implement custom AlertView and add your custom button where you want on your AlertView?

Comment: Because I'm using multiple alerts in my app and I want them to remain graphically same .. So I was just curious if there is any way to work with default alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is best link for custom `UIAlertView` that you want .

https://github.com/stavash/UIBAlertView

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

[For more get custom UIAlertView this is The Best site for any Custom Controls.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIalertView)

Choose any one form above link and add it with your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create your own custom AlertView I'm afraid:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>
> The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.
>   - [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

In regard to custom UIAlertViews, the following link might be what you're after - https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets.

Comment: +1 but also a better answer would also provide a alternative.

Comment: **As Apple does this in many locations, I don't think it violates the HIG. I can also say this with confidence because of something I learned at WWDC. I would advise you to look on the Apple Developer site under the prerelease documentation for iOS 5 on UIAlertView**